# EOL error from input() when running python script using shebang that specifies a conda environment

Tags: python, conda, user-input

I am making a python CLI that prompts user to enter input at certain times during its running. I want to use the input function for this but get EOFError: EOF when reading a line when it reaches the input() line.

I've done some testing and I think the problem is I am using a shebang on the script that makes it run with a specific condo environment. This is the minimal code needed to reproduce the problem

```
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n TEST python

def main(): # testing
    chromatogram_result = input()
    print(chromatogram_result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where TEST is my conda environment name.

The issue occurs if I run this from the command line by simply invoking the file name

```
$ ./my_file.py
```

It also occurs if I run it from terminal using a command based on the shebang

```
$ conda run -n TEST python my_file.py
```

But doesn't occur if I activate the correct conda environment and then run it

```
$ conda activate TEST
$ python3 my_file.py
```

My question is why is this occurring and is there a better way to invoke a specific conda environment in a shebang to avoid this? Or do I have to use a normal shebang and remember to activate my environment each time I want to use the script?

This is on macOS 10.14.6, using conda 4.10.3. It doesn't seem specific to one conda environment, I've tried a few different ones on my system and all give the same error with this shebang

Comment: Does `#!/usr/bin/env -S conda run -n TEST python` work? See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/477651/19512

Comment: Nope same error unfortunately

Comment: Could you try this in the script or in the IDLE: input("Enter info").replace("\x0a","").replace("\x0d","").replace("\r","").replace("\n","")

Comment: Nope, still same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Conda buffers I/O on `conda run`. You'll need the `--no-capture-output` flag to get interactive I/O:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env conda run -n TEST --no-capture-output python

def main(): # testing
    chromatogram_result = input()
    print(chromatogram_result)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

As for whether there is a better way: no, this is the best pattern I've seen for creating executable Python scripts that evaluate in specific Conda environments.

Comment: This worked, thanks for the solution and information. Can I ask for a fuller explanation of why conda buffering stdin and stdout causes the error? If its preventing user input to the terminal during execution, I would naively expect to see the prompt for entering text but not actually be able to enter anything, whereas the error indicates something is being passed to the input, just not by the user.

Comment: @user16837577 my understanding is that since the `stdin` is effectively blocked, attempting to read from it emits an EOF (end-of-file) signal, which is what the interpreter is reporting to see. However, I really don't know the details. I recall seeing discussion on the GitHub repo re: `conda run` buffering before the flag was added, so that might be worth searching...